# Looking for a Maven Artifact for: Spring + Hibernate + JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, maven

I'm new to Maven, and have the following 2 questions about Maven:

1. I'm looking for a Maven artifact that includes Spring + Hibernate + JPA. The only one that I found is one that is mixed with Flex.  For now, I want to keep it simple, and don't want to have to deal with the Flex added complexity.
2. When you download a Maven artifact such as one for Spring + Hibernate + JPA, do they already come with the necessary configuration, or Maven only handles the downloading of the libraries and files, and then I have to go in and add the necessary configuration?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking for a Maven artifact that includes Spring + Hibernate +
>   JPA. The only one that I found is one that is mixed with Flex. For
>   now, I want to keep it simple, and don't want to have to deal with the
>   Flex added complexity.

I am not aware of such an artifact. Anyway, having separate artifacts for different vendor libraries is probably a good idea in case you want to upgrade only one.

> When you download a Maven artifact such as one for Spring + Hibernate
>   + JPA, do they already come with the necessary configuration, or Maven only handles the downloading of the libraries and files, and then I
>   have to go in and add the necessary configuration?

Generally the configuration you have to do is minimal and directly related to your own environment, e.g. persistence.xml for database credentials and location, which makes it impossible to be shipped with the artifact.

Answer (score 0):

[AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) has an artifact for Spring MVC + Spring + Hibernate application.

`mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-spring-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.1.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse`