# Maven web project with JPA, Spring, Hibernate

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am getting started with with JPA. I am not running the project in a JEE container, simply using Tomcat. I want to test my DAOs (even though I read somewhere that DAOs may not be relevant with ORMs today) and have minimal dependencies on Spring and Hibernate.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/vikeshkumar/134f47b9853b26e92e64) for relevant codes and configuration.

Problems I am facing are

1. bean of type UserDao cannot be found and hence cannot be injected resulting in error, even though I can see that it is created as it's constructor runs and I have done `syso` there, BUT
2. EntityManager is Null when UserDao is initialized

If I change the test-config.xml to use `persistence.xml` which is configured for MySQL database, it creates all tables, but same errors. `hsqldb-persistence.xml` is configured to use in-memory db.

[Project Structure as it appears in Eclipse](http://ykesh.in/content/images/2014/Feb/MavenProjectStructure_PNG.png). When I run the `TestUserDao` it read correctly everything from `hsqldb-persistence.xml` which is in `/src/test/java/resources/WEB-INF/` directory.

Appreciate any help.

Thankyou.

Comment: I'd advise creating a project from a Maven archetype so you can verify your descriptors based on a working example. Take a look on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261706/looking-for-a-maven-artifact-for-spring-hibernate-jpa

Comment: I have found that when I use `Dao<User> userDao` in `TestUserDao.java`, the test case passes and data is saved as well. I don't understand what's going on and why this succeeds while using `User userDao` fails?